# Relative width of one image wrt another

Tags: fractions, percentages, ratio

Suppose I have an image:

```
120: Original Width
70: Original Height
```

I have another image:

```
20: Original Width
20: Original Height
```

Both these images have to be relative to each other (or should I say these both are in aspect ratio with each other?)

So what would be the height of second image if the height of first image decreases to 100?

Now I do know the way to get aspect ratio with changing height for one single image, which would be (if I am not wrong): `Old Width/Old Height * New Width = New Height` but how do I apply something like this to two images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "images have to be relative to each other," but I think what you want is a constant *ratio of aspect ratios*.

So, your original ratio of aspect ratios is:

$\frac{(120/70)}{(20/20)} = \frac{12}{7}$

You said that the "height of the first image decreases to 100," but I'm going to assume you meant that the height *increases* to 100. To preserve your aspect ratio, we need to calculate the new height $x$ using:

$\frac{(120/100)}{(20/x)} = \frac{12}{7}$

This leads to $x = \frac{200}{7} = 28.57$.